# access a json string from outside the call back function that read it

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, scope

```
var plane;

$.getJSON(sTailFileName, function(plane) {
    $('#upTailNum').html(plane.tailNum + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + plane.airplaneType);
        document.title="Load " + plane.tailNum;
        ....  goes on for 300+ statements ....
});
```

and it works fine. However, what I want to do is something like:

```
var plane;

$.getJSON(sTailFileName, function(plane) {});

$('#upTailNum').html(plane.tailNum + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + plane.airplaneType);
document.title="Load " + plane.tailNum;
```

but that gives me a "plane undefined" message. I need to get at plane from outside the scope of the getJSON -- or at least want to. I've tried many things including $.proxy and through closures (which I don't yet really understand), but with no success thus far.

This is my first effort in Javascript/jQuery. I'm attempting to replace an old DOS program I originally wrote back in 1988. See http://terryliittschwager.com/WB/wbjs.html for details.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Terry Liittschwager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback function to `getJSON` gets the `plane` value but doesn't do anything with it; so, when you do `plane.tailNum`, `plane` is still undefined because it was never assigned a value. Also, the `getJSON` call is asynchronous so you **can't** just do this:

```
$.getJSON(sTailFileName, function(x) { plane = x; });
```

because the `plane = x` will not have been executed (unless you get very lucky with the timing) when you try to access `plane.tailNum`.

You can replace the `getJSON` call with a synchronous [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call and assign the JSON blob to `plane` in the `success` callback or keep doing things the first way. You can always put your "goes on for 300+ statements" in a separate named function, say, `three_hundred_lines` and refer to that by name:

```
function three_hundred_lines(plane) { /* ... */ }
$.getJSON(sTailFileName, three_hundred_lines);
```

if you don't want to inline a big pile of code.

Comment: Worked fine. Actually, wanting to avoid all that inline code was my primary reason for wanting to do this, especially since that 300+ is possibly going to grow ten-fold. Many thanks.

Comment: @Terry: I usually put anything bigger than ~5 lines in a named function precisely to avoid getting lost in the nesting/scoping. Sometimes I'll put smaller callbacks in named functions just to make my code look pretty and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with AJAX calls is that they're asynchronous. You can access the returned value within the callback function because the callback function happens once the data is returned.

`$.getJSON();` just fires off the request and returns immediately. Any code that immediately follows it will be executed *before* the json data returns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$.getJSON` is an *asyncronous* method ie, the line `$.getJSON(sTailFileName...)` sends off the request *but doesn't wait around for the result to be returned* before continuing to the next line. The function that is supplied to `$.getJSON` is called once a response is recieved, which is almost certainly after the rest of the program has executed.

You shouldn't attempt to work around this. The callback function is the correct place to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

You are used to programming synchronously. You need to wrap any logic that uses the `plane` object in a function, and invoke that function from your `getJSON` callback. Something like this:

```
$.getJSON(sTailFileName, function(plane) {
    // pass "plane" along to some other function that does the work
    doStuff(plane);
});
```

The reason you are sending a `function` as an argument to `getJSON` is because you don't know when the response will be received.

Although I was born in 1988 when you were writing DOS programs, so if you want me to get off your lawn, I'm fine with that ;-)

-tjw

Comment: Many thanks! You're welcome on my lawn. However, do be aware of what I tell my grandchildren, all but one of which are older than you: Old age and treachery often overcomes youth and skill!